# Cant access mysql in spring-boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i cant access mysql using JPA in spring-boot

I am new to spring-boot and spring.

the error i got is below

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.

    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'

    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans
Action:
Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

My application.properties file has below lines

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Looking at at error what I could think is spring-boot is complaining that I didn't set (spring.datasource.jndi-name) property..... which I think is not necessary as I have given datasource url & credentials for login.

I dont know what value I should give to **spring.datasource.jndi-name**.

I appreciate any help. I am struck at this.

Comment: Show your `pom.xml`, do you have MySQL driver in your class path?

Comment: That is very interesting. Would you be able to share a sample somewhere, I'd like to understand why the other conditions aren't listed here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi user1315357.. I thought adding dependencies in pom.xml should add necessary libraries where they belong, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I thing I have messed with my maven settings. I tried uninstalling mysql & spring tool suite which didn't work. **Finally I tried deleting .m2 folder from my home directory** and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

At the begining of app development I have added to the main class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

I didn't wanted to have my database configured.
Then I just forgot about that. After delete this line the above errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

try it with:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
spring.datasource.name=
```

with an empty datasource name and the above driver, plus your other properties.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I thing I have messed with my maven settings. I tried uninstalling mysql & spring tool suite which didn't work. **Finally I tried deleting .m2 folder from my home directory** and it worked for me.